# ckeditor inserts DIV into P when using createFakeParserElement

Tags: javascript, dom, plugins, ckeditor

I'm searching couple days to solve this issue and I found these two similar questions, [issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562393/ckeditor-plugin-insert-fake-element-add-unwilling-p-tags-before-and-after), [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488016/inserting-blank-p-tags-before-and-after-fake-element) and I think both are not fully answered (or not fully understood).

The problem is, when using [createFakeParserElement](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-createFakeParserElement) function, ckeditor ignores the "realElementType" (3.) parameter when inserting to editor.

```
var div = editor.document.createElement( "div" );
div.setText( 'this is replaced by fake element' );
var fakeElement = editor.createFakeParserElement(div, "fake-element", "div", false);
editor.insertElement( fakeElement );
```

the result is

```
<p>
    <div>this is replaced by fake element</div>
</p>
```

which is wrong. It should take into account the "realElementType" param, find out the element is block, not inline, and remove the <p> tag. So the result should be just

```
<div>this is replaced by fake element</div>
```

I tried to remove the <p> tag before inserting manually, but I can't figure out how. Is it bug of ckeditor, or am I doing something wrong?

**Update:**

In the meanwhile I browse the source code and I found, that the function creates the fake element always as <img> regardless of the original type. That's why it can place into <p>, because the original <div> is validated as <img>.

I found partial solution by wraping the fakeElement to <div>. Now it removes the paragraph, but leaves it with two divs, so the solution is only partial:

```
<div>
    <div>this is replaced by fake element</div>
</div>
```